# How to return database fields from checkbox selection?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, checkbox

the code below returns the fields of a given table ("Employee"), but I need to return the fields of ALL the tables in the given database, is this possible? My assumption is a For loop which loops round the tables in the database and prints the corresponding fields but my efforts seem to be in vain

```
Public Sub getDbFields()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim dbcon As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = " & dblocation & _
                                               "\" & dbname)
    Try

        dbcon.Open()
        dbDt = dbcon.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, New Object() _
                                         {Nothing, Nothing, "Employee", Nothing})

        For i = 0 To dbDt.Rows.Count - 1
            'compile lbtables with a list of available tables from the database
            newLine()
            frmMain.lstTables.Items.Add(dbDt.Rows(i)!COLUMN_NAME.ToString())
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Data Load Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    End Try

End Sub
```

This routine will be fired from the selection of a checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return all columns on a database

```
Using con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + 
                          "Data Source=" + dblocation + "\" + dbname)
    con.Open()
    Dim schema as DataTable = con.GetSchema("COLUMNS")
    Dim dr as DataRow
    For Each dr in schema.Rows
        Dim tablename as string = dr("TABLE_NAME").ToString()    
        if Not tablename.StartsWith("MSys") then
            Console.WriteLine(dr("TABLE_NAME").ToString() + " " + dr("COLUMN_NAME").ToString())
        End if        
    Next    
End Using
```

Please note that the bang (!) syntax is not allowed in vb.net.
Also your code could work if you change

```
 dbDt = dbcon.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, New Object() _ 
                                          {Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing})
```

and this line

```
frmMain.lstTables.Items.Add(dbDt.Rows(i)("COLUMN_NAME").ToString())
```

Comment: How do I simply show all the fields of the available tables? Yours works as planned except there are some default MSsysAccess tables in their that I do not wish to show, how do I remove them?

Comment: I found your solution easier to understand, mine was constructed with help on MSDN, I'm not too sure of the difference between GetOleDbSchemaTable() and GetSchema() methods (Apart from the amount of code!!)

Comment: Simply exclude the column from the output when the TABLE_NAME column starts with "MSys", answer updated

Comment: Thank you this works as I would like it to. However, for learning puposes, is it bad practise to declare a variable within a loop ?

Comment: Well, no, why do you think so?. Local variables like that helps to write a more readable code. Sometimes they are unnecessary but the compiler is smart enough to optimize your code and, if you write code for a living, you have less problems to understand your own code in the future.

Comment: I think this because if a loop iterates round as it should, In my mind, the variable gets re-declared after each iteration and I thought this could lead to problems. Thanks for the help though it's working how it should